# Ember.JS: Observing @each, but just iterating over new/changed items

Tags: performance, ember.js

I'm currently observing some Ember arrays like so:

```
 observe_array: function() {
     this.get("my_array").forEach(function(e,i) {
         // do something
     });
 }.observes("my_array.@each");
```

Most times, if my_array is updated, multiple elements are added at once.
However, the observer fires one-by-one as each element is added, which becomes extremely inefficient. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently? Essentially, I need to be able to have a mutated array based on "my_array"

For reference, realistic sizes of my_array will be between 600-1200 elements. The "do something" block involves some operations that take a little more time - creating Date objects from strings and converting each element to json representation.

Instead of doing an observer I also tried a property with the cacheable() method/flag, but that didn't seam to speed things up very much....

Comment: do you know when you array is updated ?

Comment: @sly7_7 I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're asking, or atleast what sort of answer you're looking for. The array is actually an Ember-Data record array, and represents all elements that are loaded from a certain model.

Comment: You give me a good answer here, even if my question was a crap ^^. Try to observe my_array.isLoaded and see if it's better :)

Comment: Last time I messed with isLoaded it seemed like that isLoaded was triggered as soon as the server responded with data, and before the records were actually inserted into the associated record arrays....does that make sense? I'll look at it again when I get home, I was hoping it would work that way...

Comment: Hmm, I think it has been fixed, but you're right, this needs confirmation...

Comment: isLoaded seems to fire with each loaded record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (via comments) that your array is an ember-data populated one, you should try observing `array.isUpdating` property. I got success w/ this one.

*The only drawback is it is only set when using `.findAll()`! (so `Model.find()`)*

Comment: Well here's what I ended up doing: I have a "filteredData" filter that essentially is a store.filter on my model. Previously I tried observing isLoading, isUpdating, etc, on this...however it fired every time an item was added. Separately I was querying for items by using store.findQuery. what I ended up doing was just observing isLoading on store.findQuery, which fires only once - after it loads all the items.